# Tricky discrete math problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics, matlab, mathematica, python

[image: discrete math problems]

In the recent project, I encountered a puzzle, thought for several days, I simplified it. I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: I've looked at your proposed edit that was rejected.  I think that in the interest of readability, you should maybe add your modified code to your post, or post a separate answer of yours that explains the changes to the problem formulation that require the changes to the script.  Regarding vectorization, I don't think that's the solution.  Setting up the constraints is not where the time goes.  Almost all the time is spent in `s.check()` and there you are staring NP-completeness in the face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution for $N=7$ with the smallest value for $\omega_N$ is this:

$$ W = \begin{bmatrix}
25 & 26 & 28 & 29 & 34 & 36 & 37
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 24 & 22 & 21 & 16 & 14 & 13 \\
  27 &  0 & 24 & 23 & 18 & 16 & 15 \\
  31 & 30 &  0 & 27 & 22 & 20 & 19 \\
  33 & 32 & 30 &  0 & 24 & 22 & 21 \\
  43 & 42 & 40 & 39 &  0 & 32 & 31 \\
  47 & 46 & 44 & 43 & 38 &  0 & 35 \\
  49 & 48 & 46 & 45 & 40 & 38 &  0
\end{bmatrix}$$

This solution is generated by this [z3py](https://github.com/ericpony/z3py-tutorial) script:

```
""" Find 0 < w1 < w2 < ... < wN < 1.5 w_1 such that all values of
    2wi - wj for i != j are distinct from all wk.
"""
from __future__ import print_function
from z3 import *

N = 7
omega = [Int('omega_%s' % (i+1)) for i in range(N)]

s = Solver()

s.add(omega[0] > 0)
for i in range(1,N):
    s.add(omega[i] > omega[i-1])
s.add(2*omega[-1] < 3*omega[0])

# Impose upper bound on omega[-1] to find "smallest" solution.
s.add(omega[-1] < 38)

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+1,N):
        for w in omega:
            s.add(2*omega[i] - omega[j] != w)
            s.add(2*omega[j] - omega[i] != w)

result = s.check()
if result == sat:
    mdl = s.model()
    print('W =', ' '.join([str(mdl.evaluate(w).as_long()) for w in omega]))

    mat = [[0] * N for _ in range(N)]
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i):
            orow = mdl.evaluate(omega[i]).as_long()
            ocol = mdl.evaluate(omega[j]).as_long()
            mat[i][j] = 2 * orow - ocol
            mat[j][i] = 2 * ocol - orow

    print('\n'.join([' '.join(['{:3}'.format(item) for item in row])
                    for row in mat]))
else:
    print(result)
```

Comment: Very thanks, your solution is absolutely correct. But what confused me is that for larger N, how to find a proper sequence W.

Comment: @YanXu I've used [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) and I was able to get solutions for $N$ up to $32$ is a few seconds.  The values of the $\omega_i$'s though got quite large (approximately 4 billions) and imposing upper bounds on their values resulted in much harder satisfiability problems.

Comment: I have not known Z3 yet, needing some time to learn it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Z3 is a power SMT Solver. I have learned the Z3 tutorial, but could't model the problem. Can you tell me the Z3 code to help me understand?

Comment: @YanXu I've added the Python code I used.  For this type of problems it's usually more convenient than the SMT-LIB 2 language.  The drawback is that you have to install Z3 on your machine.

Comment: Much thanks. The python code helps me a lot.

Comment: I have understood the python code and solved my problem, thank you very much again.